# Lazy loading of Module routing path issue

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-routing

I am trying to lazy load the module with angular 2.

I have two modules

1. AppModule (main module)
2. ProductModule (lazily loaded module)

AppModule.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },

            { path: 'products', loadChildren:'app/products/product.module#ProductModule'}
        ])
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent,
        WelcomeComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here I have two routes one is default route that is blank and one is welcome screen in `AppModule`. It contains one more route `products` to initiate lazy loading of modules and relevant component that is `ProductModule`.

and now `ProductModule` looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ProductListComponent,
        ProductDetailComponent,
        ProductFilterPipe
    ],
    imports: [
        SharedModule,
        RouterModule.forChild([
            { path: '', component: ProductListComponent },
            { path: 'product/:id', component: ProductDetailComponent, pathMatch:'full'}
        ])
    ],
    providers: [
        ProductService,
        ProductDetailGuard
    ]
})
export class ProductModule {

}
```

as you can see my `ProductModule` is having empty routes (for listing product) and one route with `product/id` which shows product detail.

Now for the first route in `ProductModule` having `ProductListComponent` is activated when I navigated to **http://localhost:3000/products** which is OK but for the second route which is having `ProductDetailComponent` is activated when I navigated to **http://localhost:3000/products/product/1**.

Now for the detail screen url I do not wanted to have ***products*** in the url.

I have already tried specifying `{ path: 'products', component: ProductListComponent }` route. But unluckily it doesn't worked.

Please explain me why it needs the products in the detail screen URL and how can I make it activated on ***http://localhost:3000/product/1*** URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recognize this code. :-) Have you seen my routing course? I cover this. For lazy loaded routes the base route has to be the same. So both routes need to start with 'products'.

Here is an example:

```
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: ProductListComponent
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: ProductDetailComponent
      },
      {
        path: ':id/edit',
        component: ProductEditComponent,
        canDeactivate: [ProductEditGuard]
      }
    ])
```

The matching routing name is required because all of the lazy loaded routes need to share a parent route. Accessing that parent route for *any* child will lazy load the routes.

Comment: @DeborahK Isn't there any way out there so that I can make it `http://localhost:3000/product/1` without changing route products? Also please provide the link to your course.

Comment: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-routing/table-of-contents Thanks for asking!

Comment: To answer your question ... you can remove lazy loading. Then you can name your routes anything you want. Or you could make your routes `product` and `product/1`. They just need to have the same parent route for lazy loading to work.